# Optimal structure of a sentence

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, phrase-choice

I have a couple of questions about the following sentence:

> I built a model to classify whether or not a tweet is about economy using NLP techniques.

1. Is this a case where *or not* can be omitted? The classification is binary ("about economy" or "not about economy"). If it's indifferent to omit it, I need to know which option is the most formal.
2. Are the following sentences equivalent?

> I built a model to classify whether or not a tweet is about economy using NLP techniques.

> I built a model using NLP techniques to classify whether or not a tweet is about economy.

That is, does the position of *using NLP techniques* change the meaning of the sentence? If so, which option is preferable? The sense is that I use these techniques to build the classification model.

Comment: Hi LJG, you're asking two different questions here. Please focus on one of them, and ask a separate question for the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, you need an article before *economy* because it is something known and specific.
2. Yes, you can eliminate *or not* because the answer is either *yes* or *no*. Some consider it redundant if you don't.

> I built a model to classify whether a tweet is about **the** economy...

3. No, the position of *using NLP technique*s does not change the meaning of the sentence. However, since it's describing the model and not the economy, it's preferable to put it first.

> I built a model using NLP techniques to classify whether a tweet is about the economy.

There could be confusion about what *using NLP techniques* describes if your sentence was a little different. This might not make sense, but to illustrate my point:

> I built a model to classify whether a tweet is about investigations using NLP techniques.

It's not really clear whether you built a model using NLP techniques or you built a model about investigations that use NLP techniques.

Comment: You assume that "using NLP techniques" modifies "built", but couldn't it also modify "classify"? E.g.: "I built a model to classify (using NLP techniques) whether a tweet is about the economy."

Comment: Yes, it can describe either, but it ultimately describes the model. I suppose an even better solution would be to combine the two of them:  "I built a classification model using NLP techniques..."

Comment: @swmcdonnell but in this case how would you handle *whether a tweet is about the economy*?

Comment: You would do exactly as I said in my answer and move it closer to model and classify. Or if you mean for my example, you might say: "I built a classification model using NLP techniques to determine whether a tweet was about the economy."